# PyMongo group by: iterate over groups

Tags: pandas, mongodb, pymongo

I'm looking to iterate over groups obtained via Mongo's aggregate.
The following, for example, will print the different values of the field `field_name` from the collection:

```
collection = db['collection']
for entry in collection.aggregate([{'$group':{'_id':'$field_name'}}]):
    print entry
```

It does not, however, allow me to iterate over the different groups of entries.
With a Pandas dataframe I would do this, assuming that the dataframe `df` represents the `collection`:

```
gb = df.groupby(['field_name'])
for ix, df_g in enumerate([gb.get_group(x) for x in gb.groups]):
    print df_g
```

so that `df_g` is a dataframe corresponding to each group. Is there a corresponding `get_group` function available in PyMongo, that would return a cursor which only contains the current group?

I guess I could get the distinct values of `field_name` via aggregation and then query each group separately, but I was hoping to avoid those separate queries.

Comment: You need to add some [accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#accumulators-group) to the pipeline, e.g. `docs: {$push:"$$ROOT}` will let you to print all documents in the group with `print entry["docs"]`.  Keep in mind the 16MB limit of a document.

Comment: @AlexBlex, thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Would you like to make an answer out of it so that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some [accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#accumulators-group) to the pipeline, e.g. [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)

```
collection = db['collection']
for entry in collection.aggregate([{'$group':{'_id':'$field_name'}, docs: {$push:"$$ROOT}}]):
    print entry["docs"]
```

Please keep in mind the individual "item" [cannot exceed 16MB in BSON format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/index.html#bson-documents) so if there are many documents that share the same value in the `field_name` or the documents are big enough or both you may face an error that you cannot $push more documents to the list.

In this case you will need to $push only required part of the document instead of `$$ROOT`, e.g.

```
collection = db['collection']
for entry in collection.aggregate([{'$group':{'_id':'$field_name'}, docs: {$push:{
    _id: "$_id", 
    one_field:"$one_field", 
    another_field: "$another_field"
}}}]):
    print entry["docs"]
```

will print only 3 selected fields from the grouped documents